# What is the difference between iterating between an object's properties and an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having trouble understanding the difference between iterating through an array vs. iterating through an object's properties.

What is the difference between:

```
for (key in object) {
DO THIS
} --> for objects
```

and

```
for (var i = 0 ; i<array.length ; i++) {
DO THIS
} --> for arrays
```

If I want to compare the properties of an object to the values in an array, can I iterate through both the object and the array in the same function. For example, something like this:

```
for (var key in object){
if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
  for (i=0 ; i<array.length; i++){
  if (object[key] === array[i]){   
    filteredKeys[key] = object [key]}
```

My ultimate goal is to write a function that takes an object and an array of keys and returns a new object with only the keys found in the array.

Comment: Think you mean for instead of if. Anyways, are you asking the difference between a for-loop for an array and a for-in loop for looping through an object's enumerable properties?

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant for (var i = 0 ... ), edited my question. And yes, asking what is the difference between the two and whether I would include both in the same function if I want to compare the values in the array to the properties in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you have to understand is that arrays are just special objects with properties that are numbers (indicating index) and values indicating elements at those indices -- they have keys and values just like any object. With a `for` loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]; //iterating through the array and accessing each element
}
```

You're just accessing the the numeric keys like any other object, just through [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) because `arr.0` is invalid syntax. Now with a for...in loop, you just iterate through the enumerable properties of an object. As I've said, the indices (meaning 0, 1, 2, etc.) to an array are just keys to the array object! Thus, the above for loop does the same as this:

```
for(var i in arr) {
  arr[i];
}
```

Because the indices of the array are the keys, this iterates through the keys (indices) and thus you can access elements of the array.

---

To address your other question -- you can't iterate through an object an array with the same loop if they have different keys. Arrays are ordered with numeric indices as keys, which objects' keys can be anything. Their  keys aren't necessarily the same so accessing that key from both the array and object will not yield correct results.

Instead, if you want to filter out certain keys from an object based on if their in an array or not, try the following:

```
function filterKeysByArray(object, keys) {
  return keys.reduce((filteredObj, key) => {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      filteredObj[key] = object[key];
    }
    return filteredObj;
  }, {});
}
```

This completely eliminates the nested for loop. It only ever iterates through the keys in the passed array and reduces it down to a single object, the filtered object. It checks if the object has the property specified by the key, and if it does, it's added to the filtered object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification re objects/arrays! For the other question, that's not quite what I was referring to - will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: @Ana Ahh, I see. In this case, you couldn't really eliminate the second loop because the array loop loops through the properties 0, 1, 2, etc while the for-in loop loops through the keys of the object which aren't necessarily 0, 1, 2, etc but you could shorten it with ES6 code.

Comment: @Ana I've updated my answer with an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Objects and arrays are fundamentally different data structures in JavaScript. Objects are collections of key-value pairs, while arrays are ordered lists of data.

Iterating through object keys is different from iterating through an array in that you're accessing data in a different kind of data structure.

> My ultimate goal is to write a function that takes an object and an array of keys and returns a new object with only the keys found in the array.

This could be accomplished by doing something like this:

```
function filterObject(obj, keys) {
  var newObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] in obj) {
      newObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

For example, calling `filterObject({'one': 1, 'two': 2}, ['one', 'three'])` will produce the result `{'one': 1}`.

Comment: Sorry my phrasing was a bit unclear. I meant that the new object would only return the keys found in the array and the original object, not all the keys in the array.

For example if the object had properties name and age. And the array had ["name", "occupation"], I would only want my new object to contain the property name and the corresponding value.

Comment: Yep, you can ensure that the new object only includes keys present in the original object by adding an additional condition to your loop before adding the value to your new object. I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: But in this case, 'keys' is not defined, which is the problem I keep running into if I don't include "for (var keys in object)" in my function.

Comment: Actually the order of keys in an object, using `for...in` is guaranteed to be original insertion order according to the ECMA specification.